# Insert into DB with jQuery and get Feedback

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a MySQL Database on a Server. This is how my HTML stores thing in that DB

```
var shV = localStorage.getItem("PersName");
var idV = localStorage.getItem("codeQR");
var posV = localStorage.getItem("position");

window.open('http://*.es/insert.php?sh='+shV+'&id='+idV+'&pos='+posV,
'blank','location=no,hidden=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no');
```

The Insert.PHP File

```
<?php
try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.**');
    $shortV = $_GET['sh'];
    $idnumberV = $_GET['id'];
    $positionV = $_GET['pos'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO idtabelle (short, idnumber, position) 
VALUES (:sh, :id, :pos)");
$statement->execute(array('sh' => $shortV, 'id' => $idnumberV, 'pos' => $positionV));  
echo "$idnumberV eingetragen"; 
    $pdo = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e -> getMessage());
    }
?>
```

I want to store them without opening a new Page or show them the Insert Url. After it is in the DB i want a Feedback like "Your Data has been entered" only when they are really in the DB.

In an other HTML I search the Position by entering an ID in an Textfield. It works like I want. In the Page and a Feedback is given.

Search.html

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="search_input">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="bt1">Get Position</button>
  </form>
    <div id="div1">Testing</div>
      <div id="div2"> Here </div>
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#search").on("submit", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post("/search3.php", $("#search").serialize(), function(d){
                        if (!$.trim(d)){   
                            alert("Nothing found !");   }
                        else{   
                            $("#div1").empty().append(d);
                            localStorage.setItem("PosGet",d);   
                            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=(d);
                                }
                        });
                    });
            });
```

The Search.PHP File

```
<?php
 try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.**');
    $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $idV = (isset($_POST['search_input'])) ? $idV = $_POST['search_input'] : exit('The search was empty'); 
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT position, short FROM idtabelle WHERE idnumber = ?");
    $statement->bindParam(1, $idV);
    $statement->execute();
    foreach($statement -> fetchAll() as $row){
    echo $row['position'];
    }
    $pdo = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e -> getMessage());
    }
?>
```

How can I do it that the Insert is like the Search above in the Page and with a Feedback?
Thank you.

Comment: you may use ajax also as you did with selection step

Answer (score 0):

in your first example the code runs a new window (but hidden), so you have no chance to get a result from the inital window. You should do it like in the second provided example.

If you can use jQuery ( your examples looks like) you can use the jQuery.ajax() function

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

You also can have a success and a failure callback. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
  function(){
      console.log("success");
  },
  function(){
      console.log("error")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$dbconn = pg_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect');
}



$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $1";
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", $query);

$data = array($q);
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", $data);


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The Html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple example using PostgreSQL, for you to understand the basics. If you want more help start programming, and if you have any difficulties ask the community.

In the example above, when a user selects a person in the dropdown list above, a function called "showUser()" is executed.

The function is triggered by the onchange event.

Code explanation:

First, check if person is selected. If no person is selected (str == ""), clear the content of txtHint and exit the function. If a person is selected, do the following:

1) Create an XMLHttpRequest object

2) Create the function to be executed when the server response is ready

3) Send the request off to a file on the server

Notice that a parameter (q) is added to the URL (with the content of the dropdown list)

The page on the server called by the JavaScript above is a PHP file called "getuser.php".

The source code in "getuser.php" runs a preaper execute on a PostgreSQL database, and returns the result in an HTML table.

Explanation: When the query is sent from the JavaScript to the PHP file, the following happens:

1) PHP opens a connection to a PostgreSQL server

2) The correct person is found

3) An HTML table is created, filled with data, and sent back to the "txtHint" placeholder.